# Customising an authentication dialog in OSX with SFAuthorizationPluginView

Tags: objective-c, c, security, authorization, osx-mountain-lion

I'm currently developing a custom dialog to be displayed via an Authorization Plugin, based upon the Apple example code of "NameAndPassword", which subclasses the SFAuthorizationPluginView (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NameAndPassword/Introduction/Intro.html)

From what I understand, this should allow me to provide different types of authorization / authentication, such as, for example, developing facial recognition for authentication. The problem I have is that when my dialog is launched by the authorization services, it is embedded in a parent dialog and there is additional text automatically added that states: -

**"Type the name and password of the user in the "(null)" group to allow this".**

After many hours searching the web, I have discovered that I can remove the "(null)" group section with an undocumented environment flag of "suggested-user" (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/180052?tstart=0)

...but text still remains prompting for a password.

In testing, I can launch other available plugin dialogs by calling from my mechanism of the rules in /etc/authorization and these dialogs do not appear to be attached to the parent dialog.

Does anyone know what I need to do to prevent the default text being displayed, or even better, how to have my dialog launched, independently from the parent dialog? Is this even possible with inheriting from SFAuthorizationPluginView?

Thanks.

Comment: So, the answer is don't inherit from SFAuthorizationPluginView, but instead create a separate project bundle with its own, custom UI which is then used as a SecurityAgent plugin and referenced as a mechanism from the /etc/authorization database